# Software to convert 30fps videos to ultra slow motion videos?

Tags: windows, gratis, video-editing

I am looking for a software using which I can convert a normal 30fps 720p video to ultra slow motion?

I have:

Windows 8, 64 bit

2 GB RAM

Dual Core processor

Software must be:

1) Easy to use

2) Freeware (if not available, recommend paid softwares)

Comment: Are you are aware that no software can reliably create `tween frames for normal video? Some might semi-realistically smooth frame changes in simple scenes, but it will not recover blurred images, or ever reach the quality of video shot with specialist cameras, even at smallish factors. Can you give the frame-rate factor you are aiming for (e.g. effective 90fps), and some indication of the quality or effect you hope to achieve. You definitely will *not* be seeing anything like this: https://www.youtube.com/user/ultraslo

Answer (score 1):

For me the best for this job is the [SONY Vegas](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/download/trials/vegaspro), but it is not a freeware. You can do slow motion via holding the `ctrl` key and expand the length of the video (drag the border of the video on timeline) you want to have a slow motion effect. Or you can also try this [solution](https://www.moviestudiozen.com/free-tutorials/sony-vegas-pro/511-how-to-slow-down-go-pro-video).

[image: sony vegas slow motion effect]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), OS X, Linux, Android
- Is CLI so you can batch
- [Can change the speed of a video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)